# How to add an Index on a virtual colum with Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-mobile-services

i have two classes, User and Following, i created two relationships to the same class, but i need to constraint uniqueness on the pair of foreign keys.

I have tried adding an index, but it doesn't work, the index is not added to migration code, i think it's because User and FollowingUser are virtual.

How add uniqueness on a pair of virtual foreign keys?

Thanks in advance.

Note: Im working with Azure Mobile App Service, and primary key fields are added automatically.

```
public class Following : EntityData
{

    [Index("IX_FriendshipUniqueness", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_FriendshipUniqueness", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual User FollowingUser { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

}

public class User : EntityData
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Followings = new HashSet<Following>();
        this.Followers = new HashSet<Following>();
    }


    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Following> Followings { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("FollowingUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Following> Followers { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the relationship advice column I penned a few days ago - it assists in the understanding of how you can constrain Azure Mobile Apps requests: https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-26-relationship-advice/

Short version - even though EF6 allows such constraints (and I'm not saying it does - I'm not that into EF to make a definitive statement), Azure Mobile Apps does not provide the ability to do those constraints.  It needs to be enforced in your client code.